# Storing the content of an xml child node based on a parent node's attribute in php

Tags: php, xml, xpath, parent

I'm trying to display the biggest image url returned from an xml result. So far the largest returned is 400 high so I hardcoded 400 in. If possible I would like to select just the largest in case in the future I get results that don't have a 400 height image in them.

I've tried

```
$x = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x);

$imageURL=$xml->categories->category->items->product->images->image[@height='400']->sourceURL;
```

Which gives me "syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ']'".

And I also tried:

```
$imageURL= $xml->xpath("/categories/category/items/producct/images/image[@height='400']/sourceURL");
```

But got a bad link.
Here is the XML:

```
 <images>
        <image available="true" height="100" width="100">
            <sourceURL>
                Someurl.com
            </sourceURL>
        </image>
        <image available="true" height="200" width="200">
            <sourceURL>
                Someurl.com
            </sourceURL>
        </image>
        <image available="true" height="300" width="300">
            <sourceURL>
                Someurl.com
            </sourceURL>
        </image>
        <image available="true" height="400" width="400">
            <sourceURL>
                Someurl.com
            </sourceURL>
        </image>
        <image available="true" height="399" width="400">
            <sourceURL>
                Someurl.com
            </sourceURL>
        </image>
    </images>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`->image[@height='400']` is a direct PHP array reference. This'd be interpreted as supressing errors (`@`) on a `defined()` constant (`height`), and trying to set its value via an assignment `='400'`.

For your xpath version, remember that an xpath query returns a DOMNodeList, not an actual DOMElement. To get the URLs you need from the query results, you have to ierate over the node list:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query(...) {
foreach($nodes as $node) {
   $url = $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Ok I still can't get this to work. Can you please give me a step by step breakdown? Using your code I get "Fatal error: Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::query() "

Comment: Ah. for SimpleXML, it's just `$xml->xpath(...)`. $xpath->query is for when you're using DOM/DOMXpath.

Comment: I still can't seem to get it to work, the error is fixed (thank you) but using this code $nodes = $xml->xpath("/categories/category/items/product/images/image[@height='400']/sourceURL"); foreach($nodes as $node) { $imageURL = $node->nodeValue; } I don't get the urls, actually I don't get anything if I echo the variable.

Comment: Try `var_dump($nodes)`, see if any nodes are actually being found.

Comment: query()'d return either an array of results or boolean FALSE. null shouldn't ever come out if it.

Comment: Whoops I used var_dump($node) instead of $nodes. I get array(0) { }

Comment: Ok. So the xpath query's returning no results. Your XML sample doesn't have any `<categories>`, `<category>`, etc... tags, just images. did you omit that part from the sample?

Comment: Yes I did. Ill put up a whole sample in the original post.

Comment: No worries. Just eliminating possibilities. I'd try simplifying the query down to bare essentials, Maybe just `//sourceURL` and then work backwards from there.

Comment: Ok. The interesting part is that if I just put $imageURL=$xml->categories->category->items->product->images->image->sourceURL I get an imagURL it's just the first one listed.

Comment: Even having the query as just //sourceURL or //image returns array(0){}. Is there some kind of issue with loading with simplexml and then trying to use xpath?

Comment: Don't think so. But you could try using DOM in php instead. wouldn't take much to switch over to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Below code might help...


    $xmlSQLProcedures = new DOMXPath($xmlSQLProcedures);
    $strProcedureName = $xmlSQLProcedures->query("//SQLProcedure[@ID='$sSQLProcedureID']")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $nodeParameters = $xmlSQLProcedures->query("//SQLProcedure[@ID='$sSQLProcedureID']/Parameters/Parameter");
    $ParamCount = $nodeParameters->length-1;
    for ($i=0;$i<=$ParamCount;$i++) {
        echo $nodeParameters->item($i)->getAttribute("Name").'<br>';
    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SQLProcedures>
<!--    **********   FOR KEYWORD IN LOCAL LANGUAGE    *************    -->
    <SQLProcedure ID="001070001">
        <Name>P_ManipulateKeywordsInLL</Name>
        <Parameters>
            <Parameter Name="LanguageId"/>
            <Parameter Name="KeywordId"/>
            <Parameter Name="KeywordInLL"/>
            <Parameter Name="ActionFor"/>
            <Parameter Name="KeywordInLLId"/>
            <Parameter Name="Keyword"/>
            <Parameter Name="KeywordList"/>
            <Parameter Name="SessionId"/>
            <Parameter Name="WarehouseId"/>
        </Parameters>
    </SQLProcedure>
</SQLProcedures>
```